# Is there anyway to calculate $B_n$ from this equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$1-y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n (e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi})\cos(n\pi y)$

I encountered this equation when solving a Laplace equation and I believe I didn't solve the $B_n$ correctly. The way I did it was the usual Fourier's trick:

$B_n(e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi})=2\int_0^1(1-y)\cos(n\pi \
y)dy=\frac{2(1-(-1)^n)}{n^2\pi^2}$.

However, after plotting the result, I found the solution doesn't match one of the boundary conditions. Then I realized Fourier's trick might be invalid here because the term $e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi}$ depends on $n$ so I can't just take them out of the integral with $B_n$. I wrote this program to plot the results.

[image]

After realizing that, I found myself stuck so I wonder if anyone knows how to calculate $B_n$ in this equation.

Thanks a lot!

The Laplace equation and what I've got are presented here:
[image]

Comment: Please describe how you think the result is wrong. Due to the even symmetry, the series can only converge to $1-|y|$ on $[-1,1]$, and the convergence is rather convincing already with 6 terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you so much for your reply! I included the program I wrote to show why I think it's not correct.

Comment: You need to treat the coefficient for $n=0$ separately, as there the integral does not contain some cosine, just the average of the function. Also the division by $n$ in the coefficients shows that $n=0$ is a special case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann. I'm sorry for my late response. I think I did considered the case of $n=0$. But I find if $n=0$, the exponential term $e^{n\pi}-n^{-n\pi}$ will make the whole term 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument for $\lambda=0$ is wrong. The boundary conditions only apply to the complete solution series, not to each single term.

Still, the zero boundary conditions allow an extension of the solution as odd function in $x$ and $2$-periodic function in $y$ with even symmetry axes in $y=0$ and $y=1$ (and thus for all $y\in\Bbb Z$). This fixes what terms can appear in the solution expansion, removes some cases.

For the bilinear term this means that to be periodic it has to be constant in $y$ direction, $u_0(x,y)=cx$. To get the correct Fourier expansion in $x=1$, one gets the term $\dfrac{x}{2}$, so that the remaining zigzag curve is shifted down to mean zero.
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{k=0,~n=2k+1}^\infty \frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}\frac{\sinh(n\pi x)}{\sinh(n\pi)}\cos(n\pi y)
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and patience! That's such a stupid mistake of mine.